# C# dynamic type Object property First is always null

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net, enumerable

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to create a dynamic Object in C# and try to iterate over its members.

The Json layout equals:

```
[{{"id": "Name"}, {"spec": {More Data}}, {{"id": "Name"}, {"spec": {More Data}}, ...]
```

When I try the following:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

      foreach (dynamic entry in jsonObj){

            dynamic first = entry.First;
      }
```

I receive an Object first, that contains `null` even though entry has runtime generated members First and Last, which are anything but `null` (When I look at them in Visual Studio in debug mode).

I *can* access the members though. When using:

```
dynamic first = entry["id"];
```

I receive the correct value, instead of `null`. So there has to be data inside.

Is it impossible to access runtime generated members in a loop, or is there another mistake?

PS: I know, that I'd have to call `entry.First.First` to access the value of `"id"`. But this returns just `null` as well.

A screenshot of the content of my dynamic Object:

[image]

Comment: There is nothing in the Json that can map to `First` property. If you want the dynamic object to be a collection then the json needs to be in collection format and collection format in json starts with `[` and ends with `]`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you, I corrected that mistake. I checked the Object in code as well. And it was written as Collection.

Also I added an image of the dynamic Object's contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonString = @"
[
    [   {   item1: { 'id':      'Name'      },
            item2: { 'spec':    'More Data' }
        },
        {   item1: { 'id':      'Name'      },
            item2: { 'spec':    'More Data' }
        }
    ]
]";

            dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

            foreach (dynamic row in jsonObj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Row\n{row}\n--------------------");
                foreach (var column in row)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Column\n{column}\n--------------------");
                    foreach (var item in column)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"item\n{item}\n--------------------");
                        foreach (var part in item)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"part\n{part}\n--------------------");
                            foreach (var subpart in part)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"subpart\n{subpart}\n--------------------");
                                foreach (var subsubpart in subpart)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"subsubpart\n{subsubpart}\n--------------------");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
Row
[
  {
    "item1": {
      "id": "Name"
    },
    "item2": {
      "spec": "More Data"
    }
  },
  {
    "item1": {
      "id": "Name"
    },
    "item2": {
      "spec": "More Data"
    }
  }
]
--------------------
Column
{
  "item1": {
    "id": "Name"
  },
  "item2": {
    "spec": "More Data"
  }
}
--------------------
item
"item1": {
  "id": "Name"
}
--------------------
part
{
  "id": "Name"
}
--------------------
subpart
"id": "Name"
--------------------
subsubpart
Name
--------------------
item
"item2": {
  "spec": "More Data"
}
--------------------
part
{
  "spec": "More Data"
}
--------------------
subpart
"spec": "More Data"
--------------------
subsubpart
More Data
--------------------
Column
{
  "item1": {
    "id": "Name"
  },
  "item2": {
    "spec": "More Data"
  }
}
--------------------
item
"item1": {
  "id": "Name"
}
--------------------
part
{
  "id": "Name"
}
--------------------
subpart
"id": "Name"
--------------------
subsubpart
Name
--------------------
item
"item2": {
  "spec": "More Data"
}
--------------------
part
{
  "spec": "More Data"
}
--------------------
subpart
"spec": "More Data"
--------------------
subsubpart
More Data
--------------------
```